# Connecting to Windows 7 using SMB protocol version 2.1 (Linux since 4.13)

Tags: windows-7, linux, networking, samba

Since the update to version 4.13 of the linux kernel my laptop running Arch Linux at first couldn't connect to the Windows 7 machines in my home network anymore. I've figured out that this is due to the update of the SMB protocol from version 1 to 3 and since Windows 7 runs on 2.1 the Arch laptop wasn't compatible to it any longer.

My problem now is: At first I had to set it back to version 1 in order to be able to connect my Arch notebook to the Windows 7 machines, albeit Windows 7 should use the protocol version 2.1 (client max protocol = NT1 instead of SMB2 or SMB2_10). Now (for whatever reason) it does work with SMB2_10 and even without using the "client max protocol" option at all, but when I connect with smbclient -L, I get the message that the client is "Reconnecting with SMB1 for workgroup listing," and when I force the smbclient to use 2.1 (client min protocol = SMB2_10), I get the response: "SMB1 disabled -- no workgroup available."

Is it possible to setup my Samba configuration in a way that the client actually uses SMB 2.1 when connecting to Windows 7?

Answer (score 1):

This looks as if you have actually DISABLED SMB2 on the Windows 7 side (maybe as part of your earlier troubleshooting).

Samba 4.x on Linux should automatically negotiate the proper SMB version with the other side. Prefer SMB3 and fall back to SMB2 (because Win7 doesn't do SMB3, you need Windows 8 or 10 for that).

SMB1 should be disabled everywhere. It is obsolete and a major security risk. (Via SMB1 it is relatively easy to get Administrator-access on Windows network shares.)

Comment: I just checked and the SMB2 protocol version is enabled on Windows 7 but I've now disabled SMB1 via the registry (set HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanServer\Parameters\
SMB1 to 0) and again I can't access the machine from Linux anymore (error message of "smbclient -L hostname": Error NT_STATUS_UNSUCCESSFUL). 
In /etc/samba/smb.conf I had set "client min protocol" to SMB2_10 and I also tried it with SMB2 - but either way, it doesn't work.

Comment: That is really odd. For some reason the client on the Linux machine doesn't see that Win7 offers SMB2 and attempts to fall back to SMB1. Did you reboot after making changes on Win7? Some of these only activate properly after a reboot.

Comment: Yes, I did a reboot.